# How can I sort by index in Daru?

Tags: ruby, dataframe, daru

In Daru, I know that by `Daru::DataFrame#sort` we can sort dataframe by its column, but I noticed method does not work if we want to sort dataframe by its index.

#### Question

- I believe `Daru::DataFrame#sort` is for sorting by column.  How can I sort a dataframe by index?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Daru::DataFrame source](https://github.com/SciRuby/daru/blob/master/lib/daru/dataframe.rb) it looks like there are several methods for iterating through the frame by index, such as `each_index`.

There's also a method for reindexing: [Daru::DataFrame#reindex](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/daru/Daru/DataFrame#reindex-instance_method) which I believe could be used to replace the current index with a new index that you could build by sorting the old index with `index.sort`:

```
frame.reindex(frame.index.sort)
```

Disclaimer: I don't know what a dataframe is or what daru does or what the indexes look like.